# How to display the content of my page on all the screen with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables and I am facing an issue how to display the content of my page on screen.

I added `<div class="container-fluid">` then I inserted `width="100%` and `height="100%"` inside `<table>` but my page is not displayed as expected on the screen.

The width is fine but the height no, my table looks to be displayed on only half the page. Here is my code.

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr class="active">
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

I tried also

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="table-responsive">
```

before

```
<table>
```

but still can't make it work. Any idea please what am I missing in Bootstrap? Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe there are less entries in your table..in that case how table will be 100% height

Comment: It's not really a Bootstrap issue. In order to make an element have 100% height its parents have to be 100% height too. So you would need to start with html and body being height: 100% or min-height: 100%. Then you'd need to also make .container-fluid and .row and .col-md-12 100% height. But your table will probably only be as tall as its content.

Comment: I made you a code pen with your sample code, https://codepen.io/xXSirensxOpusXx/pen/jYzxVQ To me the code works as expected. You have coded a table footer and header along with 4 rows of data.